# Why is http server unreachable when i try to connect

Tags: javascript, node.js, http

I have this simple code:
But every time i ran it. it starts it self but when i search for **localhost:8080** it told me destination unreachable. What did i wrong? I really dont know.

```
const http = require('http');

const requestListener = function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200);
  res.end('Hello, World!');
}

const server = http.createServer(requestListener);
server.listen(8080);
```

Comment: Try `127.0.0.1:8080`. It is possible that `hosts` file is not configured.

Comment: thank you so much im very dumb. thank for your time!